# Manipulate a value in a webpart and use it somewhere else

Tags: lookup-column, data-view-web-part, dispform, datasource

I hope you can help.

We have two lists :  countries and customers

```
Countries fields : Country Name + Language
Customers fields : Customer Name + Country Name
```

In the dispform of customer, I need to check the value of language of customer country and pass into a hyperlink we implement in dispform (based on DataFormWebPart).

We have a huge list and I cannot change country name type to lookup field.

Thank you for any hints

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup column named CountryName1 and select Language along with that. 
Copy values from original Country Name to this newly column using powershell.

Either hide the original column and use this newly created column going forward.
or on new form copy the value from CountryName to CountryName1 using code.